What does “Invicus” mean in “The Continental: From the World of John Wick?”
“Invicus,” what does it mean?

“Invicus on Continental grounds. Red light has been activated.”


Which episode? Sounds like a code name or code word. We need context.

Also I believe it's "Inimicus on Continental ground."

Inimicus - Latin for enemy

@Paulie_D - There were only three episodes :-)

The line in Brothers in Arms is actually

"Red Light Active. Inimicus on Continental Ground"

Per the wiki;

Inimicus (pronounced ini-mik-cus) is one of the Continental Hotel's emergency protocols. Inimicus is only declared when an individual violates the "neutral" status of Continental Hotels. During Inimicus, business may be conducted on continental grounds, however, only against individuals found to be in violation of Continental rules. Inimicus can be initiated by pressing a red button in the hotel manager's office, or by order of the hotel manager.
When a Continental hotel is placed under Inimicus, an alarm will sound, along with a PA announcement, stating "Red light active. Inimicus on Continental ground."

In this instance Frankie has made himself a target by killing multiple hotel guests and attacking the facilities.
